# how do you style a form already inside django

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm using django-registration. I'd like to update the AuthenticationForm in 'django.contrib.auth.forms'. Specifically, I would like to pass the 'attrs' dict to add a few attributes. How do I update a form that comes with django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to subclass AuthenticationForm, change the attrs in constructor, pass the form to login view and write a new entry in urls.py.

This is a nightmare: in order to add html attribute to a field it is necessary to use python subclassing, to know how exactly django's form metaclass work (`self.fields['field'].widget.attrs`, not just `self.field.widget.attrs`), to know regexes (for urls.py), to know how django's urls.py work (should you put the overriding line before of after `include('django.contrib.auth.urls')`?) and to know where is the auth form and auth view imported from.

And now the "commercial break": just use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks for your task ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the views that come with auth and override the form parameter with your own form:

```
django.contrib.auth.views.login(request[, template_name, redirect_field_name, authentication_form])
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login).